# How to download MyPaint

Tags: downloads

Just started with Ubuntu. Want to download the MyPaint software. I went ito the Ubuntu "MyPaint" page and it's available on the Software Center, but I can't figure it out the 'Choose an Application' bit, nor the send to AptURL  What's that? All info greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:achadwick/mypaint-testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mypaint mypaint-data-hires
```

Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/01/install-mypaint-110-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

To install from Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install mypaint mypaint-data-extras
```

---

**OR**

**NOTE:-** Be careful in using testing packages as these softwares may contain bugs.

Official [`ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~achadwick/+archive/ubuntu/mypaint-testing) of MyPaint to get the latest builds:

To install it, type the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:achadwick/mypaint-testing -y; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install mypaint mypaint-data-extras
```