# How to install MyPaint

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, software-center, paint

I want to install MyPaint and followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/823043/158636).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:achadwick/mypaint-testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mypaint mypaint-data-hires
```

But it gives this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mypaint-data-hires is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mypaint-data-extras

E: Package 'mypaint-data-hires' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried to install it from `ubuntu software centre` where it gives `unauthenticated` error. even accepting this error nothing installs.

Terminal installation

```
sudo apt-get install mypaint mypaint-data-extras
```

gives this error

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mypaint mypaint-data mypaint-data-extras
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mypaint-data mypaint mypaint-data-extras

Install these packages without verification? [y/N] n
```

I denied installation because its unverified. Should I install it?

If this app cant be installed can you suggest some ***light weight*** paint apps?

EDIT

Result for `sudo apt-key update`

```
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg': resource limit    
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair.gpg': resource limit
gpg: key 437D05B5: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key FBB75451: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key C0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key EFE21092: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 4
gpg:              unchanged: 4
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` before installing?

Comment: yep I did that before  trying to install mypaint

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  I looked in http://ppa.launchpad.net/achadwick/mypaint-testing/ubuntu/dists/ and didn't see support/testing evidence for artful/17.10  (so are you using 17.10?)

Comment: Forgot to add tag I am using 14.04

Comment: What is the output of *sudo apt-key update*

Comment: @stumblebee I have edited the question and added the output there

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. It was not a problem of MyPaint but something to do with GPG and PPA. I have followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92897/158636).

I first did `sudo apt-get update` and recieved error simialr to this
[image]

and then went to `software and updates > Other softwares` and unchecked all error causing PPAs

[image]

Then when I updated `sudo apt-get update` it showed additional error in `GPG error...NO_PUBKEY` This is solved by

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>
```